# MVC and JavaServer Faces

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsf, jakarta-ee

1. When we speak of a **view technology** are we meaning the framework that we use to create the web pages like JSP or Facelets? Practically in the MVC pattern is it a PDL that render the **VIEW**?
2. In some Java EE books the **MODEL** is related to backing beans but, generally, in design patterns books the model is related to the data. So what's a MODEL?

Comment: @asgs: Page Description Language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What components are MVC in JSF MVC framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104094/what-components-are-mvc-in-jsf-mvc-framework)

Comment: @BalusC Thanks! I've only known it as Scriptlets thus far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When we speak of a view technology are
>   we meaning the framework that we use
>   to create the web pages like JSP or
>   Facelets?

Both can be considered as view. Anything that your app puts to user is a view. For example if I show some reports to user in the form of PDF then it's a view. Technically it would be JasperReports View.

> In some Java EE books the MODEL is related
>   to backing beans but, generally, in
>   design patterns books the model is
>   related to the data. So what's a
>   MODEL?

Model in broader term is your classes that simulates Business Model in your app. And I would say it is backing beans.

---

**See Also**

- [What are the   M V C   in JSF framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104094/what-components-are-mvc-in-jsf-mvc-framework/)

Answer (score 0):

Please see http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2004/jw-0719-jsf.html?page=1. It is very well explained here!

Following is an extract from a relevant part of the article.

> A multitiered architecture partitions
>   the whole system into distinct
>   functional units—client, presentation,
>   business-logic, integration, and
>   enterprise information system (EIS).
>   This ensures a clean division of
>   responsibility and makes the system
>   more maintainable and extensible.
>   Systems with three or more tiers prove
>   more scalable and flexible than a
>   client-server system, in which no
>   business-logic middle tier exists.
>
> The client tier is where the data
>   model is consumed and presented. For a
>   Web application, the client tier is
>   normally the Web browser. The
>   browser-based thin client does not
>   contain presentation logic; it relies
>   on the presentation tier.
>
> The presentation tier exposes the
>   business-logic tier services to the
>   users. It knows how to process a
>   client request, how to interact with
>   the business-logic tier, and how to
>   select the next view to display.
>
> The business-logic tier contains an
>   application's business objects and
>   business services. It receives
>   requests from the presentation tier,
>   processes the business logic based on
>   the requests, and mediates access to
>   the EIS tier's resources.
>   Business-logic tier components benefit
>   most from system-level services such
>   as security management, transaction
>   management, and resource management.
>
> The integration tier is the bridge
>   between the business-logic tier and
>   the EIS tier. It encapsulates the
>   logic to interact with the EIS tier.
>   Sometimes, the combination of the
>   integration tier and the
>   business-logic tier is referred to as
>   the middle tier.
>
> Application data persists in the EIS
>   tier. It contains relational
>   databases, object-oriented databases,
>   and legacy systems.

Comment: You might want to quote the relevant part here, just in case, the URL is broken in the future.