# EJB injections vs only JSF managed beans

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb, apache-tomee

I don't know may be my question is completely meaningless, but I can't find any straight information about it.

I had my JSF + Tomcat application and it worked just fine. I want to implement Restful services and JAAS logic. In order to do that, I switched to TomEE++.

Switching to TomEE means that my server will now be more heavy and I'm afraid than it will require more `cpu` and `ram` resources than I have in my Amazon AWS micro instance.

**The question is:** Will the performance drop down if I switch from only JSF managed beans to JSF + EJB?

**The sub-question is:** what EJB injections can do, and JSF managed beans can not do? (JSF does not allow cyclic injections for example)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *Will the performance drop down if I switch from only JSF managed beans to JSF + EJB?*

Measuring is knowing. But generally, this concern makes no sense.

---

> *what EJB injections can do, and JSF managed beans can not do? (JSF does not allow cyclic injections for example)*

Generally, they are not intented to be interchangeable. Each have their own clear responsibility. You use JSF bean management annotations to manage beans for front-end (JSF pages). You use EJB bean management annotations to manage beans for business services (BOs/DAOs). That's it.

To learn how JSF+EJB(+JPA) are supposed to work together head to the concrete examples and explanations shown in the following answers:

- [JSF Service Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011392/jsf-service-layer/13012973#13012973)
- [JSF managed-bean EJB injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626291/jsf-managed-bean-ejb-injection/8627413#8627413)
- [Filter do not initialize EntityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934447/filter-do-not-initialize-entitymanager/7934604#7934604)
- [JSF request scoped bean keeps recreating new Stateful session beans on every request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887140/jsf-request-scoped-bean-keeps-recreating-new-stateful-session-beans-on-every-req/8889612#8889612)