# am i using correct way of JSF coding?

Tags: jsf, backing-beans, entity-bean

I'm new in JSF. Can i use this way of coding instead of using EL in JSF view? and correct me if there is something wrong in my coding or should i use better way.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class RegistrationBacking extends Root {
    @EJB
    private UserManagerLocal userManager;
    public String register(){
        Map<String, Object> parameterMap = getRequestMap();
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserName((String) parameterMap.get("userName"));
        user.setPassword((String) parameterMap.get("password"));
        user.setEmail((String) parameterMap.get("email"));
        try{
            userManager.registerUser(user);
        } catch(UserExistsException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RegistrationBacking.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            getContext().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, getBundle().getString("loginExist"), ex.getMessage()));
            return null;
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RegistrationBacking.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            getContext().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, getBundle().getString("loginError"), ex.getMessage()));
            return null;
        }
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: This belongs in http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: wouldn't be easier if User was an attribute of your backing bean and if your EL had values like user.userName, user.password and user.email?

Comment: I thought if i want to change member variables name of entity bean, i would be in trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You're basically manually grabbing the submitted values from the request parameter map instead of binding the input values to the model. You're manually filling the model in the controller's action method. You won't be able to perform JSF-managed Conversion and Bean Validation on those inputs.

The right way is the following:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{registrationBacking.user.userName}" />
    <h:inputSecret value="#{registrationBacking.user.password}" />
    <h:inputText value="#{registrationBacking.user.email}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Register" action="#{registrationBacking.register}" />
</h:form>
```

And then in the backing bean:

```
private User user;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    user = new User();
}

public String register {
    try {
        // ...
    }
}
```

#### See also:

- [Passing a JSF2 managed pojo bean into EJB or putting what is required into a transfer object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246141/passing-a-jsf2-managed-pojo-bean-into-ejb-or-putting-what-is-required-into-a-tra/)
- [Creating master-detail pages for entities, how to link them and which bean scope to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459903/correct-usage-of-session-scope-in-two-page-master-detail-user-interface/)
- [JSF Service Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011392/jsf-service-layer)

Comment: Thank you. why do you instantiate user in PostConstruct function?

Comment: Otherwise it stays `null` and you can't call setter methods on `null`. It's by the way "method", not "function". This is Java, not JavaScript or PHP or whatever.