# Is JSF MVC2 and how do MVC1 and MVC2 differ

Tags: model-view-controller, jsf

How does MVC1 differ from MVC2? Is JSF MVC2? I was told by an interviewer that JSP is MVC1. Is it true?

Answer (score 2):

The right terms are ["Model 1 MVC pattern"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_1) and ["Model 2 MVC pattern"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_2).

In Java terms, Model 1 MVC pattern has the "view" and "controller" in the same place (e.g. a single JSP file with `<jsp:useBean>` or *scriptlets*, or a single servlet with `out.println()` writing HTML). Model 2 MVC pattern separates the "view" and "controller" physically. The JSP/Facelets page is the view and a servlet is the controller. This allows multiple views to make use of a single controller (according the [front controller pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/3542297#3542297)). Note that when there's no means of a model (essentially a simple Javabean class holding the data which is created/manipulated by the controller and presented by the view), then there's also no means of a MVC pattern.

JSF is definitely Model 2 MVC. The controller is the `FacesServlet`. JSP can be either Model 1 or Model 2, depending on the presence of a servlet as front controller and the JSP file being inaccessible/unusable without invoking the controller first. [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) contains solely Model 2 examples.

#### See also:

- [What components are MVC in JSF MVC framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104094/what-components-are-mvc-in-jsf-mvc-framework)