# Which is the controller in JSF MVC

Tags: java, jsf

As everybody know, JSF is an MVC. Its Model is the Managed(Backing) bean , View is the JSF/XHTML/JSP page.But which one is the Controller.JSF LifeCycle books/articles doesnt specify this.

Answer (score 1):

FacesServlet acts as controller
You can get very good explanation by BalusC here
[What components are MVC in JSF MVC framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104094/what-components-are-mvc-in-jsf-mvc-framework)