# RequestParams and PathParams in pure JavaEE controller servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, java-ee-7

for a `@webservle`t annotated `servlet`, how can I do something similar to spring mvc:

```
@Path = my/custome/path/{id}
```

and then use the id in the servlet code?
  or do 
`@requestParam (for post)` ?

and use those params in the code.

Note: I want pure java-ee solution, not with some framework like spring, or struts etc.

Comment: The pure JavaEE way of doing that is to use JAX-RS.

Comment: @JBNizet 1) theres is NO other way? 2) if no, can you give an example of jax-rs controller? 3) can you give an example of a non-pure javaee way too?

Comment: 1. Of course there is another way: implement it yourself, or use a framework sitting on top of servlets (like Spring MVC) which does it. 2. There are plenty of Jax-RS tutorials and example online. Use Google. 3. There are plenty of examples and tutorials using Spring-MVC (for example) online. Use Google.

Comment: right. got you. thank. take a look at these. I share same thoughts . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360391/mvc-pattern-in-java-ee-and-migrating-from-spring-to-java-ee-7?noredirect=1#comment37671564_24360391        https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/why_java_ee_6_is