# JSF Creating Forms is there a Best Practice?

Tags: forms, jsf

I have used mainly the first option, but I came upon the second option, and it seems to do everything faster with less code. Which way is better for creating forms using JSF? Is there a better option for creating form for an application with many server and client side validations? I really do not like to have a constructor like `new Person()`. What would you advise me? Thank you.

**Option 1:**

View:

```
<h:inputText value=#{bean.fisrtName}/>
<h:inputText value=#{bean.lastName}/>
<h:commandButton action=#{bean.submit()}/>
```

Bean

```
private firstName;
private lastName;

public String submit(){
    Person person = new Person(firstName, lastName);
    // do something with person
}
```

**Option 2:**

View

```
<h:inputText value=#{bean.person.fisrtName}/>
<h:inputText value=#{bean.person.lastName}/>
<h:commandButton action=#{bean.submit()}/>
```

Bean

```
private Person person

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    person = new Peson();
}

public String submit(){    
    // do something with person
}
```

Comment: So what's wrong with option 2, besides all the typos and missing quotes?

Comment: Option 2 is better, especially if you have more than one entity-type instances in the bean and more fields in the entities.

Answer (score 0):

The way you delevop your managed beans depends on the deepness you put into the MVC approach provided by JSF. If you want to develop a fullworthy JSF application (based on MVC grounds) then you'll basically have, as a starting point:

- **Facelet page** as *the view*: it represents information and handles user actions;
- **Managed bean** as *the controller*: it processes actions and delegates rendering to the right view;
- **Entity** as *the model*: it holds all the data.

In a small beginner-style application you can mix the model with the controller but as the application grows management of such beans could be troublesome. In real-world applications managed bean typically contains relevant entities a its members.

So, option 2 is a clearer MVC approach with a better separation of concerns.

For a bit wider picture consult [What components are MVC in JSF MVC framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104094/what-components-are-mvc-in-jsf-mvc-framework).