# What is JSF built on?

Tags: java, jsf

I finished learning *JSPs/Servlets*, and now starting to learn the **JSF** framework. As I was learning it, I started to wonder: is **JSF 2.0** build based on servlets? When a request comes to a `.xhtml` page, is it handled by (one of the) core-framework servlets, or is it built on an even lower-level technology, and originally handled by the Webserver itself?

Comment: I think, these tags has association with the question and makes question better searchable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is built on top of `Servlet`, main controller servlet is called [`FacesServlet`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/javadocs/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.html), This servlet loads your `faces-config.xml` file and other configuration while initialization

---

- [`FacesServlet` source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-api/2.2.8/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.java#FacesServlet)
- [What components are MVC in JSF MVC framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104094/what-components-are-mvc-in-jsf-mvc-framework)