# is DispatcherServlet a controller in spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In Jsf FacesServlet works as a controller. I want to know what infact is controller in spring mvc is it dispatcherservlet or the class annotated as @controller?

Comment: It depends on point of view. This JSF-targeted answer also applies to Spring MVC: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5104094

Comment: in reality in spring mvc we have only one controller and it is DispacherServlet and the classes annotated @Controller are just normal classes.