# Why Controller should call View in MVC pattern?

Tags: java, jsf, model-view-controller

I am trying to understand MVC pattern correctly.

I am using **Java** and **JFS**, which means that each HTML page is linked with back-end Java **View** class. Then **View** class calls **Controller** to retrieve some data. **Controller** use **Data** class if needed.
For me it is logical and seems like it is described in this way on this image:

[image]

But on this Image I can see another situation, when a front-end HTML calls a Controller class, which is not logical for me.

[image]

Both images are taken  [from here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/mvc-architecture), but other resources gives me the same confusion.

Please, advice where do I have wrong understanding and what should I read to understand it correctly ?

Comment: "Send Request"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What components are MVC in JSF MVC framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104094/what-components-are-mvc-in-jsf-mvc-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you my own understating of MVC may be it will help you too.

**Modal** -> Contains functions process data which comes from the database (Note it is not the actual database. It's just like a shop keeper who knows that when you buy something they are surpossed to pack it for you )

**Controller** -> If you get data from a user e.g passwords and you are surpossed to checkin if it has a certain chararcters. Functions that are surpossed to do that are the controllers. (Note you could do both Controllers and views in the same place but we divide it to simplify work.)

**views** -> Views are just  like redirectors to the controllers that are surpossed to process what ever the user requests for.

So actually in your second image the **requests and response from the browser** should be pointing to the **views**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104094/what-components-are-mvc-in-jsf-mvc-framework#5104604