# Where to use FacesContext object?

Tags: jsf

Is it a good idea to use FacesContext object with its methods in the application controllers? I mean, in opinion the FacesContext helps us mostly to manage the components and elements from GUI so I think it is not a very good idea to use it to much in the application controllers.  So, I use the FacesContext methods to get the necessary information in the Beans and after that a just send the data to the controllers.

Is my approach right?

Comment: It depends on what you mean when saying `controller`. ([see this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104094/what-components-are-mvc-in-jsf-mvc-framework)) Your question is quite vague so far. Generally FacesContext is usable in CDI managed beans of JSF applications or @ManagedBeans in older JSF applications. Additionally it's used in JSF Converters, Validators, Components, Listeners etc.

Comment: From the duplicate: *"Note that the service layer should by itself not have any JSF dependencies. So any (in)direct imports of `javax.faces.*` in the service layer code indicates bad design."*